# Multiple rows showing in listbox, but only one column from worksheet is displayed in listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, listboxitem

I have a userform that searches through information on a worksheet. It's supposed to display the rows matching the search criteria inside of a listbox named "lbSrchMatchingResults"; unfortunately, it only displays the first column of each matching row. My solution builds on code provided by CPearson (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) and Jon Acampora (http://www.excelcampus.com/tools/find-all-vba-form-for-excel/). The subroutine responsible for populating the listbox is listed below:

```
Private Sub FindAllMatches()
'Find all matches on activesheet

Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindWhat As Variant
Dim FoundCells As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim arrResults() As Variant
Dim lFound As Long
Dim lSearchCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim rw As Range, c As Long  '<<<< added

'Do search if text in find box is longer than 1 character.
If Len(FSearchAssets.tbSrchSearchString.Value) > 1 Then

    Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

    FindWhat = FSearchAssets.tbSrchSearchString.Value
    'Calls the FindAll function
    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
        arrResults(1, 1) = "No Results"
    Else
        'Add results of FindAll to an array
        ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 14)
        lFound = 1
        For Each FoundCell In FoundCells

            'add the matching value and address
            'arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Value
            'arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Address

            Set rw = FoundCell.EntireRow 'get the full row for the found cell
            'add the first 13 values from that row to the listbox
            For c = 1 To 13
                'arrResults(lFound, 2 + c) = rw.Cells(c).Value
                arrResults(lFound, c) = rw.Cells(c).Value
            Next c

            lFound = lFound + 1
        Next FoundCell
    End If

    'Populate the listbox with the array
    Me.lbSrchMatchingResults.List = arrResults
Else
    Me.lbSrchMatchingResults.Clear
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `FoundCells` holds only one cell.

Comment: I've verified that it holds more than one cell. If you plug in the code with multi-column sample code on a worksheet, you'll see that it will hold multiple cells.

Comment: `For Each FoundCell In FoundCells` I meant the former.

Comment: How do you suggest that I solve my problem?

Comment: Dump row by row with a loop instead of array? Others may suggest far better architecture.

Comment: Populating a multi-column listbox:  http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/populate_userform_listbox_or_combobox.html

Comment: Tim: I looked at the link that you provided, but I had trouble understanding how the author's suggestion will address my problem. Could you please provide a code snippet using the code that I posted to show how you would solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry - I did some testing and you *should* be able to populate a multi-column listbox by assigning a 2D array to the `List` property (I didn't know that was a thing...)  I'm not sure what you mean by "it only shows the first column of each matching row" - your code should display a single cell value and the address for that cell on each row of the listbox - you don't see that?

Comment: Your code works for me as posted.  Did you set the `ColumnCount` property on the listbox?

Comment: Changing the "ColumnCount" property from one to two now displays the first cell of each matching row and the address of that row. Each row in the worksheet contains 12 columns of data. How would I modify the above code to show the remaining 11 columns in the listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your listbox column count to 14 and try this:

```
Private Sub FindAllMatches()
'Find all matches on activesheet

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindWhat As Variant
    Dim FoundCells As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim lFound As Long
    Dim lSearchCol As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim rw As Range, c As Long  '<<<< added

    'Do search if text in find box is longer than 1 character.
    If Len(FSearchAssets.tbSrchSearchString.Value) > 1 Then 

        Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

        FindWhat = FSearchAssets.tbSrchSearchString.Value
        'Calls the FindAll function
        Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                                FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                                EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                                BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
        If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
            arrResults(1, 1) = "No Results"
        Else
            'Add results of FindAll to an array
            ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 14)
            lFound = 1
            For Each FoundCell In FoundCells

                'add the matching value and address
                arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Value
                arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Address

                Set rw = FoundCell.EntireRow 'get the full row for the found cell
                'add the first 12 values from that row to the listbox
                For c = 1 To 12
                    arrResults(lFound, 2 + c) = rw.Cells(c).Value
                Next c

                lFound = lFound + 1
            Next FoundCell
        End If

        'Populate the listbox with the array
        Me.lbSrchMatchingResults.List = arrResults
    Else
        Me.lbSrchMatchingResults.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim: Sorry for the delay; I just recently saw your reply. I'm testing it now.

Comment: Tim: Your solution mostly works; one column is duplicated and I no longer need to include the address in the listbox. I posted another question requesting input on removing variant because it's a performance hog.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question whether all of the found items were expected to be in the same column: that's why I put both the found value and the full row content as distinct columns.  How many rows are you expecting to find?